# setting focus to a child window with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, focus

I have the following script:

```
var a = window.open( "http://sitea.net" );
var b = window.open( "http://siteb.net" );

a.setFocus();
```

I would expect the focus to go to the first window (sitea.net), but instead the latest child opened is focused (siteb.net). How can I make the first window focus?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the focus to a child window without refreshing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032101/how-to-set-the-focus-to-a-child-window-without-refreshing-it)

Comment: not really... that explains how to decide to either load a popup or use an existing one. I want to be able to switch focus between two different windows that I know are there. But somehow the above code doesn't work.

Comment: I can only set focus to a child when I put a function in it to pop an alert. If I call that from the parent window the child focuses, but that's very annoying and takes away a lot of the wanted functionality

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above code.  The "window.open" causes both sites to open even without the a.setFocus.

Putting both of the variables within a function should stop the dual loading of the windows.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/latoyale/GAKFL/28/

Also I noticed while using your original code that both windows will not open if .setFocus is declared above window.open.  Maybe this problem also has something to do with the code positioning of setFocus...

Comment: I tried that... didn't work either. Even tried setting focus to a window a second later using setTimeout, that didn't even work. It seems the window isn't focussing. I tried calling a function on the child windows, setting focus to self in the child windows didn't work, pulling an alert in a child did put focus to it, but inserting alert would take away the functionality I need.

Comment: also tried a.focus() which should work... but it doesn't change focus unless I pop an alert in one of the child windows... the code example you submitted doesn't make much sense, I don't see how that's different from what I'm doing...

Comment: The code I submitted only allows the correct window "a" to open up, instead of both windows opening.  The code you submitted causes both windows to open up because of the "window.open"

Comment: I want both windows to open. And I want to be able to switch between the two from my parent window. So I pulled the code back to the bare minimum to be able to test focus, but for some reason focus only changes if I pop an alert on the child window... I wrote a function in the child window called from the parent, but that isn't able to put focus on itself either...

Comment: So question remains: how can I put focus on either one of the child windows... they both open, that's not the problem...